# Can someone translate this clip into english?

Tags: expressions

A streamer said this and I have no idea what he said, could someone please write out what he's saying and the translation? (Skip to 10 secounds)
https://clips.twitch.tv/SparklyOriginalTrianglePeteZaroll

Answer (score 1):

> "Oh putain ! Ce bijou ! Ah, j'suis refait [...] On fait des stratégies étranges"

...Aaaand I wasn't able to understand the rest of it either (19 seconds - 25 seconds).

> Oh putain

Well, that's typical french interjection, which degree of vulgarity seriously varies with the context. Here, the guy is just happy (go to n°3 [here](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=putain)).

> Ce bijou

*"What a gem"*, *"This is marvellous"* (but I quite exagerate it here)

> J'suis refait ("Je suis refait")

Literally, *"I'm done again"*. Used to mean that [you got fooled](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/%C3%AAtre_refait/67427), but nowadays it is almost the contrary. Basically *"I'm so happy (again)"*

> On fait des stratégies étranges

(Not sure about this one) *"We have strange strategies"* ?